# PBI | Ranking dynamically based in different levels of product granularity

Tags: powerbi, dataset, dax, analytics, business-intelligence

I hope everyone that's reading this message is having an wonderful day
I'm running into a problem, that I would really appreciate your help :slightly_smiling_face:

I have a dataset in PBI, where I have to Rank per 3 different LEVELS of granularity (Cat1, Cat2, Cat3).

**WHAT I WANT?**

Sales Rank per Category 1 and Brand:

- I want to rank by the total Sales (Brand in Category 1) / Total Sales (Cat1)

Sales Rank per Category 2 and Brand:

- I want to rank by the total Sales (Brand in Category 2) / Total Sales (Cat2)

Sales Rank per Category 3 and Brand:

- I want to rank by the total Sales (Brand in Category 3) / Total Sales (Cat3)

Explaining further:

**Example 1:**

Having Category 1 filtered, Category 2 filtered and Category 3 filtered I want to:

Rank by the Sales of each Brand in each Category 3 Item / Total Sales(Cat3 item)

Columns Cat1, Cat2 and Cat3 are filtered in the Matrix

1. Company ABC has 1000$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body and segment from Cat3 Body Milk
2. Company XYZ  has  800$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body and segment from Cat3 Body Milk
3. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body and segment from Cat3 Body Milk

Find in **BOLD** the expected OUTPUT

Expected Output:

| Brand | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 | SalesQuantity | Sales MS % | Rank by MS % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Beauty | Body | Body Milk | 1000 | **50%** | **1** |
| XYZ | Beauty | Body | Body Milk | 800 | **40%** | **2** |
| DZA | Beauty | Body | Body Milk | 200 | **10%** | **3** |

**Example 2:**

Having Category 1 filtered, Category 2 filtered and Category 3 NOT filtered I want to:

Rank by the Sales of each Brand for each Category 2 Item / Total Sales(Cat2 item)

Example:

Columns Cat1, Cat2 are filtered in the Matrix

1. Company ABC has 1000$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body
2. Company ABC has 300$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Hair
3. Company XYZ  has  800$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body
4. Company XYZ  has  500$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Hair
5. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Body
6. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Hair
7. Company DZA has  250$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty and
   segment  from Cat2 Hands

Find in **BOLD** the expected OUTPUT

Expected Output:

| Brand | Cat1 | Cat2 | Sales Quantity | Sales MS % | Rank by MS % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Beauty | Body | 1000 | **50%** | **1** |
| ABC | Beauty | Hair | 300 | **30%** | **2** |
| XYZ | Beauty | Body | 800 | **40%** | **2** |
| XYZ | Beauty | Hair | 500 | **50%** | **1** |
| DZA | Beauty | Body | 200 | **10%** | **3** |
| DZA | Beauty | Hair | 200 | **20%** | **3** |
| DZA | Beauty | Hands | 250 | **100%** | **1** |

**Example 3:**

Having Category 1 filtered, Category 2 NOT FILTERED and Category 3 NOT FILTERED I want to:

Rank by the Sales of each Brand for each Category 1 Item / Total Sales(Cat1 item)

Example:

1. Company ABC has 1000$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty
2. Company ABC has 300$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Home
3. Company ABC has 300$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Men's
   Clothing
4. Company XYZ  has  800$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty
5. Company XYZ  has  500$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Home
6. Company XYZ  has  500$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Men's
   Clothing
7. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Beauty
8. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Home
9. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Men's
   Clothing
10. Company DZA has  200$ in Sales in the segment from Cat1 Women's
    Clothing

Find in **BOLD** the expected OUTPUT

Expected Output:

| Brand | Cat1 | Sales Quantity | Sales MS % | Rank by MS % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | Beauty | 1000 | **50%** | **1** |
| ABC | Home | 300 | **30%** | **2** |
| ABC | Men's Clothing | 300 | **30%** | **2** |
| XYZ | Beauty | 800 | **40%** | **2** |
| XYZ | Home | 500 | **50%** | **1** |
| XYZ | Men's Clothing | 500 | **50%** | **1** |
| DZA | Beauty | 200 | **10%** | **3** |
| DZA | Home | 200 | **20%** | **3** |
| DZA | Men's Clothing | 200 | **20%** | **3** |
| DZA | Women's Clothing | 200 | **100%** | **1** |

**What I need from you?**

1. The Measure Market Share Volume % is well built? I Want that the measure calculates based in the Cat filtered

MS Volume % =
DIVIDE (
CALCULATE ( SUM(FACT_SALES[SALES_QTY] )),
CALCULATE (
SUM (FACT_SALES[SALES_QTY] ),
ALLEXCEPT (DIM_PRODUCT,DIM_PRODUCT[Cat1],DIM_PRODUCT[Cat2],DIM_PRODUCT[Cat3] )
),

2. What could be an example formula to give me what I want? I've tried with RANKX several times, but not seeing the expected results (you can find Rank MS % Measure that i'm trying to build in the link sent)
3. Any other suggestion to produce a similar output but with another structure?

**DUMMY DATA:**

Please find in the link [PBI + Dataset] [PBI + Dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZkPw7QZXEucUKO1JAqEWboc8DmJ97FkA)

Thank you very much

Diego